# Best way to draw QPixmap with 'color mod'

Tags: qt, qt5

Some rendering libraries allow to set a 'color mod' (for example, in SDL2 you do it with `SDL_SetTextureColorMod`) when drawing a texture, which would effectively multiply the colours of the pixels by a given value before drawing. What is the best way to achieve this in Qt5, for example, when drawing a `QPixmap` with `QPainter::drawPixmap`? So far the only option I see is to use a temporary pixmap, fill it with the colour by which I want to multiply, then draw on it with `QPainter::CompositionMode_Multiply` and then draw the result to the target device. Is there a more straightforward way that maybe does not include drawing to a temporary pixmap?

Answer (score 2):

You can do without the temporay pixmap by drawing a rect with size of your pixmap in your target:

```
QPixmap const src(":/images/img.png");
painter->fillRect(QRect(QPoint(0, 0), src.size()), Qt::red);
painter->setCompositionMode(QPainter::CompositionMode_Multiply);
painter->drawPixmap(QPoint(0, 0), src);
```

If your pixmap has transparent regions, you can add `painter->setClipRegion(src.mask());` before calling `fillRect`.

Comment: I don't think this will work for the case where the pixmap that I want to draw contains semi-transparent pixels (with alpha not equal to 0 or 1), and I want to blend it onto a device that already has some background in it.